# React component rendering without overlay

Tags: css, reactjs, components

Hey I am pretty new to React and I have a misunderstanding about the rendering of my components so if I use two different components in another to render them e.g. in a page they will always overlap.

```
export class PageComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <TripForm />
        <br />
        <TinyEditor />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but I want them to align underneath each other as they were written as only one component respecting each other as content blocks.
So where's my mistake or misunderstanding about components can anybody explain?

Comment: did my answer work?

Comment: Yes it did kind of I had the style on position: absolute on one of the components but your answer was helpful in the end thank you!

Comment: Chris, no worries mate. mark the answer correct if you can to let others know it is finished. have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they will behave stylistically as you tell them too

you have this

```
export class PageComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <TripForm />
        <br />
        <TinyEditor />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

if `tripForm` and `TinyEditor` are `div` components they will behave as such and essentially will be the same as this

```
export class PageComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div />
        <br />
        <div />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

there will never be overlap unless you tell it to in your CSS

if you want them to align them, apply css to this class `.container`

`.container { display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }` should be a start